# Continue after promise rejection in .catch statement: Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, readline

### Expected behaviour:

The code will continue after the .catch block prints the error to the console

### Behaviour:

The code exits the program.

### Methods tried:

I tried using a return; statement: that did nothing. I also tried using a continue; statement, which errored out. I also tried wrapping the whole thing in a trycatch, and that resulted in the same behaviour.

### Code:

```
function readProxies() {
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(debug.proxy_file),
            output: process.stdout,
            terminal: false
        });
        rl.on('line', (line) => {
            var ipPattern = new RegExp(/(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}/g);
            var justIp = ipPattern.exec(line);
            var oneProxy = ip2proxy.getAll(justIp[0])
            if (oneProxy.Is_Proxy == 0) {
                console.log('worked')
                fetch('https://returning-json.workers-sites-examples.workers.dev/', {
                    agent: new ProxyAgent(debug.protocol + '://' + line, {
                        tunnel: true, // If true, will tunnel all HTTPS using CONNECT method
                        timeout: 2000, // Time in milli-seconds, to maximum wait for proxy connection to establish
                    })
                })
                    .then(res => res.text())
                    .then(body => console.log(body))
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })
            } else {
                console.log('not worked')
            }
        });

        rl.on('close', () => {
            console.log('closed')
        });
}
```

Comment: are you sure, the error is caused by the `fetch` because this is the only thing that is guarded by the `catch` right now. If the exception happened somewhere else, there is nothing to catch it ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you see and what you expect? Do you just see a single error logged and then "closed", as if there is only one `line` event being processed?

Comment: Do you see the "closed" message on the console? Because that would mean, the input stream for readline was closed (https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_close) but that won't happen if the application exited because of an exception ...

Answer (score 0):

Edit: derpirscher, thanks!

The "closed" printed into the console keyed me in a bit into what was going on. Turns out, everything WAS going smoothly, and I just had to put a `return;` in the catch statement, then fill the debug.proxy_file with more proxies. Only one of them passed the first check, so it would make sense that only one was tested. Thank you for your help!